# Can I create a delay queue in ZeroMQ

Tags: zeromq

Amazon Queues have something called a delayed queue 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

Is it possible to create one using PUSH/PULL in ZeroMQ, and so how?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, you should implement it by yourself.